# What type of admin account security is required for E-commerce android application with firebase-Auth?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Sir, i'm working on E-commerce android application, in which a login in system is designed for only one specific person,

I'm not understand how to create unique account for only one admin, because admin is responsible for adding, removing or updating products as well as he is responsibles for adding or removing accounts for shipper boys.

Which mechanism is required to maintain security for admin , that's other then unique admin no one create account in firebase authenction and access the database and place changing in database.

I also need mechanism in which when application is terminate, admin account is logout automatically from firebase authenction, when application starting again it requires verification from unique admin which is already created in database (This is our basic purpose).

Please help me, and forgive me if i asked simple or basic question from community, because i can't understand how to achieve this task.
Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Firebase(Firestore)